# C Stack Implementation

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, stack

I'm implementing the Stack ADT in C. The Stack follows an array implementation where the array is an array of `void *`. The following behaviour puzzles me, can anyone provide some insight? The address of i, `&i`, is always the same, thus, the values I obtain by popping it off should be the same, but it isn't. In addition, the numbers are in reverse order. What am I missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stack.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Stack* s = Stack_Create(10);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        Stack_Push(s, &i);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf("%d\n", *((int *)Stack_Pop(s)));
    }
    Stack_Destroy(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Stack Implementation:

```
#include "stack.h"

struct Stack
{
    size_t size;
    size_t top;
    void** e;
};

Stack* Stack_Create(size_t n)
{
    Stack* s = (Stack *)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    s->size = n;
    s->top = 0;
    s->e = (void**)malloc(sizeof(void*) * (n + 1));
    return s;
}

int Stack_Empty(Stack* s)
{
    if (s->top == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

void Stack_Push(Stack* s, void* e)
{
    if (s == NULL) return;
    if (s->top == s->size) return;
    s->top = s->top + 1;
    s->e[s->top] = e;
}

void* Stack_Pop(Stack* s)
{
    if (Stack_Empty(s)) return NULL;
    s->top = s->top - 1;
    return s->e[s->top+1];
}

void Stack_Destroy(Stack* s)
{
    if (s == NULL) return;
    free(s->e);
    free(s);
}
```

Header File:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#ifndef __STACK_H__
#define __STACK_H__
struct Stack;
typedef struct Stack Stack;

Stack* Stack_Create(size_t n);
void Stack_Destroy(Stack* s);
void Stack_Push(Stack* s, void* e);
void* Stack_Pop(Stack* s);
int Stack_Empty(Stack* s);
#endif
```

Comment: The address of the variable you're using or your loop iteration is replicated throughout the stack. You only ever push one address on the stack, that of `&i`. Consequently, dereferencing *anything* you pop will result as a dereference of `&i`, which just happens to also be the loop-control variable you're using. I.e. you're loop is modifying `i`, and because `i`'s address is the only thing on the stack (repeatedly), your print is nothing more than `printf("%d\n, i);` Do this: put a `printf(%p\n", e);` in your stack push function and watch what happens.

Comment: Thank you, answer is now consistent when using j as index.

Comment: Using `j` as index for the second loop, this should print 10 (the value of `i`) every time.

Comment: Actually managed to find a previous question on this: [Odd problem with pointer while implementing a linked list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562362/odd-problem-with-pointer-while-implementing-a-linked-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the values I obtain by popping it off should be the same, but it isn't

Yes it is.

> the numbers are in reverse order

No they aren't. You are printing the successive values of `i` in the second loop, which ranges from 0 to 9. Note the `*`:

```
*((int *)Stack_Pop(s))
```

`*&i` is simply `i`.